# Split array into multiple array performance

Tags: arrays, powershell, split

I tried to split below array into multiple smaller array using PowerShell. But it takes much time to output the text file line by line. Is there other way to improve the performance?

Original array (`$FRUITARRAY`):

```
ORANGE,1,4,5,6,7,8
APPLE,1,3,2,4,5
ORANGE,2,4,5,6,7,8
ORANGE,3,4,5,6,7,8
APPLE,2,3,2,4,5
ORANGE,4,4,5,6,7,8
ORANGE,5,4,5,6,7,8
APPLE,3,3,2,4,5
APPLE,4,3,2,4,5
```

Desired output arrays:

`$ORANGERRAY`:

```
ORANGE,1,4,5,6,7,8
ORANGE,2,4,5,6,7,8
ORANGE,3,4,5,6,7,8
ORANGE,4,4,5,6,7,8
ORANGE,5,4,5,6,7,8
```

`$APPLEARRAY`:

```
APPLE,1,3,2,4,5
APPLE,2,3,2,4,5
APPLE,3,3,2,4,5
APPLE,4,3,2,4,5
```

Code:

```
$FRUITARRAY = Get-Content 'D:\work\fruit.txt'

for ($i=1; $i -lt $FRUITARRAY.Length; $i++) {
    if ($FRUITARRAY[$i].Split(',')[0].StartsWith('ORANGE')) {
        $FRUITARRAY[$i] | Out-File "D:\work\ORANGE.TXT" -Append
    }

    if ($FRUITARRAY[$i].Split(',')[0].StartsWith('APPLE')) {
        $FRUITARRAY[$i] | Out-File "D:\work\APPLE.TXT" -Append
    }
}

$ORANGEARRAY = Get-Content "D:\work\ORANGE.TXT"
$APPLEARRAY  = Get-Content "D:\work\APPLE.TXT"
```

Comment: I tried to re-format your code, but it's too broken to be salvaged (it's not valid powershell). Please update the post with _the actual code_ that's currently running slow

Comment: Edited the actual code. There could be 500k lines in the text file.Thanks...

Comment: If you do not require the files (`ORANGE.TXT` and `APPLE.TXT`), I would highly recommend to keep everything in memory. You might just concat an array by first assigning an empty array:` $ORANGEARRAY = @()` and than add the new values like: `if ($FRUITARRAY[$i].StartsWith('ORANGE')) {$ORANGEARRAY += $FRUITARRAY[$i]}`. (btw., there is no use spiting it if you use `.StartsWith`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arguably the most elegant solution would be `Group-Object`:

```
$fruits = Get-Content 'D:\work\fruit.txt' | Group-Object { $_.Split(',')[0] }

$apples  = $fruits |
           Where-Object { $_.Name -eq 'apple' } |
           Select-Object -Expand Group
$oranges = $fruits |
           Where-Object { $_.Name -eq 'orange' } |
           Select-Object -Expand Group
```

Comment: Why not use the name of the group to name the variable? `foreach($fruit in $fruits){Set-Variable -Name "$($fruit.Name)Array" -Value ($fruit.Group)}` provided the actual names are valid as variable names.

Comment: @LotPings I consider dynamically named variables a bad practice, so I will not recommend doing that. If anything, put the groups in a hashtable.